# What does the "is_active" mean in the block producer list?

Tags: cleos, block-producer

When I run

```
cleos system listproducers -j
```

I got detailed block producer info in json format, and there's a field called "is_active", which I'm not quite sure what it means? Does it mean the node associated with the block producer account is currently online? How does the EOS system determine which producers are active or not? I couldn't seem to find any docs on this particular "is_active" field?

Comment: probably means it's among the 21 active bps that are scheduled to produce in the ongoing round

Comment: @confused00, I'm pretty sure that's not the case, as all the hundred or so block producers returned from the listproducers command have the "is_active" field showing 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean the node associated with the block producer account is currently online?

No, the `is_active` field is set manually, and it's a heuristic that is used to choose BPs that should build blocks next round. Those with `is_active == False` are given a negative score when BPs are [ordered by votes](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/905e7c85714aee4286fa180ce946f15ceb4ce73c/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp#L75) so they end up being ignored while inactive.

> How does the EOS system determine which producers are active or not?

When an account registers as a producer using the [`regproducer`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/contracts/eosio.system/voting.cpp#L37-L61) method, they are automatically considered active (`is_active == True`). Similarly, when the [`unregproducer`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/contracts/eosio.system/voting.cpp#L63-L71) method is called, the producer is deactivated (`is_active == False`).

Although `unregproducer` requires the authority of the producer that is being deactivated, the `eosio.system` contract can use [`rmvproducer`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.cpp#L88-L95) to deactivate producers if enough BPs sign to use the multisig `eosio` account to send the action. The last point is particularly important because it enables proposals [such as this one](https://medium.com/@liquideos/increasing-stability-of-the-eos-blockchain-11921477549e) where BPs that cannot produce blocks are unregistered by the system, and then they can reregister later without losing their votes or blocking the network.

---

Side note: The terminology may be a bit confusing because people may often use "active BPs" to refer to the 21 BPs that are producing in a round (e.g. [Dan's comment](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2278#issuecomment-390005322),) while the `is_active` field has different semantics.